# EC2 instance volume replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way or third party tool that would allow synchronous block level replication between an EC2 instance volume (or RAID volume) in one AZ and an EC2 instance volume in a separate AZ ?

Answer (score 1):

We are using GlusterFS https://www.gluster.org/ for replication in a single AZ

It should be possible to set it up for multiple AZ

Comment: Great Tks, if anyone has done this via Gluster or similar love to hear if it worked

Comment: More thinking, does Gluster support instance volumes (as well as EBS) and would you be better using asynch (geo based) replication across zones to minimise latency?

Answer (score 1):

I've used CloudEndure for this (https://www.cloudendure.com) with success. They have really solid block level replication tech for AWS.